# What are the key differences between SubgraphOS and Tails?

Tags: tails, subgraph

Subgraph has a new ["Adversary resistant computing platform" called 'Subgraph OS'](https://subgraph.com/sgos/index.en.html) that seems superficially similar to Tails. What are the differences between the two projects?

Answer (score 2):

First, subgraph doesn't exist yet so it's tough to compare. But it appears to implement a sandbox for every application. Tails does not do this.

Answer (score 2):

Mentioning only a very few,

1. Subgraph has a Grsecurity/PaX hardened kernel. Tails doesn't.
2. Subgraph lets you choose which application to route through Tor and which through clearnet or VPN very easily. Tails doesn't.
3. Subgraph can be used as a live USB, but it can also be installed as the default system, something that Tails doesn't.
4. Subgraph implements a sandbox for every application.
5. Tails is a more mature project than Subgraph.

Comment: Subgraph doesn't implement a sandbox for *every* application yet, only for some applications.